JetBrains IntelliJ remote debug classes without source code
I've been successfully debugging remote JVM (running OpenLiberty) under IntelliJ (CE).
For the most part it is easy breeze.
But sometimes I need to step into 3rd party code. Moreover, code not bundled with my app (as dependency), but loaded by the container (its own machinery).
I remember (maybe a prior version of IntelliJ) it opened an editor with decompiled code (naturally the line numbers are off, so stacktrace is unusable), with the option of "attach source code".
But today I don't even have access to this editor.
This unavailability hinders the ability of setting breakpoints and anticipating code flow.
How can I have back the editor for classes whose source code is unavailable?
Or at least some class structure (fields and methods) so I can set breakpoints.
